# soap header doesnt appear in http traffic when coming from biztalk

Tags: web-services, soap, biztalk, biztalk-2010

I am trying to construct a message in biztalk to send out to a web service. When I call the web service from c# i see the traffic(from fiddler) as basically this:

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <s:Header>
        <h:AuthenticationInfo xmlns:h="urn:Ticket" xmlns="urn:Ticket" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
            <userName>user_name</userName>
            <password>password</password>
            <authentication/>
            <locale/>
            <timeZone/>
        </h:AuthenticationInfo>
    </s:Header>
    <s:Body xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
        <CreateTroubleTicket xmlns="urn:Ticket">
            <ServiceID>asd</ServiceID>
            <ServiceType>service Type</ServiceType>
            <Impact>1</Impact>
            <Priority>1 - Critical</Priority>
        </CreateTroubleTicket>
    </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

and this returns an expected response. I found instructions online on how to get this working in BizTalk, ie. add the soap header (http://threaddump.blogspot.com/2005/01/how-to-send-soap-headers-in-biztalk.html, or http://www.apress.com/9781430232643 where there is a walkthrough and code for chapter 2.13) and I have followed them. However I haven't been able to create the header you see above. I see just the body come through fiddler when biz sends off to the web service;

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><s:Body><ns0:CreateTroubleTicket xmlns:ns0="urn:Ticket">
  <ns0:ServiceID>ServiceID_0</ns0:ServiceID> 
  <ns0:ServiceType>ServiceType_0</ns0:ServiceType> 
  <ns0:Impact>1</ns0:Impact> 
  <ns0:Priority>1 - Critical</ns0:Priority> 
</ns0:CreateTroubleTicket></s:Body></s:Envelope>
```

I can get the promoted property assigned to the string I want. I know this because when I look at my suspended message(after it fails to get a legit response from the service) I see that property with the value I gave it in the message context:

[image]

To be clear about what I did to get this far; I addded a property schema with target namespace 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/BizTalk/2003/SOAPHeader' and with a single element named 'AuthenticationInfo' that has its Property Schema Base set to 'MessageContextPropertyBase'. I then assign this in an orchestration to the promoted property of the message as:

```
MessageInwHeader(TempBizConsumeHeader.AuthenticationInfo)= @"<ns0:AuthenticationInfo xmlns:ns0=ur..."
```

So if anyone sees something wrong here or knows why I am not acutally seeing this header in the request let me know. Maybe I need a special send pipeline, or I need to define an entire envelope? I think with WCF services(which the one I'm calling is not) there is a ready made property, WCFOutboundHeaders or some such thing. Id love for there to be one of those I could use...

Comment: How are you connecting to the service?  Why do you need to see the soap envelope?

Comment: Im connecting to it through the port generated by Biz when you 'add generated items'. I need to see the envelope when sending through Biz to make sure its got the same header that exists when I call through C#(because the call works when I call from C# but not from Biz). The idea is to get the two envelopes(when calling through C# and when calling through Biz) to look the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you are trying to send message with custom header to WebService through BizTalk send port.

There is built-in property named `WCF.OutboundCustomHeaders`, you should use it and your property assignment would be be like this:

```
MessageInwHeader(WCF.OutboundCustomHeaders) = "<headers><h:AuthenticationInfo xmlns:h=\"urn:Ticket\" xmlns=\"urn:Ticket\" xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\" xmlns:xsd=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\"><userName>user_name</userName></h:AuthenticationInfo></headers>";
```

If you are going to frequently use these headers, probably you may create some helper for this.

Comment: Thanks FCR this did it! And of course I had tried using this property before but the xml in my header was malformed so it haddnt worked.